# How to parse string to bigInteger in velocity template?

Tags: java, velocity, biginteger

How to parse string to bigInteger in velocity template?

If we have integer then we can do as below (but not sure, how we could this for bigIntger type):

```
#set( $Integer = 0 )
#set( $input1InInteger = $Integer.parseInt($input1) )
```

Comment: If you can live with `java.lang.Long`, you could do: `#set($int = 0)
#set($long = $int.longValue())`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a little helper class in your context to do this:

```
public class NumberHelper {
    public static final NumberHelper INSTANCE = new NumberHelper();
    private Exception lastError = null;

    private NumberHelper() {
        // intentionally empty
    }

    public void setLastError(Exception lastError) {
        this.lastError = lastError;
    }

    public Exception getLastError() {
        return lastError;
    }

    public BigInteger parseBigInteger(String numberAsString) {
        BigInteger retVal = null;

        try {
            retVal = new BigInteger(numberAsString);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            setLastError(e);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

now put it into your context:

```
context.put("numberHelper", NumberHelper.INSTANCE);
```

and use it on your template

```
#set( $Integer = 0 )
#set( $input1InInteger = $numberHelper.parseBigInteger($input1) )
```

Comment: @Dhaval Your question suggests that velocity now supports BigInteger. What version are you using?

Comment: Velocity supports all Java objects... I don't see why BigInteger wouldn't have always been supported from that point of view